# Manipulating 15.000+ rows in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, csv

I'm working on an application that requires a lot of data. This data is stored in SAP (some big enterprise planning tool) and needs to be loaded in an Oracle database. The data I'm talking about is 15.000+ rows long and each row has 21 columns.

Every time an interaction is made with SAP (4 times a day), those 15.000 rows are exported and have to be loaded in the Oracle database. I'll try to explain what I do now to achieve my goal:

1. Export data from SAP to a CSV file
2. Remove all rows in the Oracle database
3. Load the exported CSV file and import this into the Oracle database

What you can conclude from this is that the data has to be updated in the Oracle database if there is a change in the row. This process takes about 1 minute.

Now I'm wondering if it would be faster to check each row in the Oracle database for changes in the CSV file. The reason why I ask this before trying it first is because it requires a lot of coding to do what my question is about. Maybe someone has done something similar before and can guide me with the best solution.

Comment: If you're using a tool such as SQL*Loader to put the data into the final table it's unlikely to be quicker to change just the changed data.

Comment: The way we have done a similar thing is to define an external table on the CSV file. Then define a materialized view as SELECT * FROM EXT_TABLE with REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND. The materialized view then is the table we query in Oracle and create indexes on and so on. The process of refreshing the data then becomes two step - first export data to CSV file, then call DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH to complete refresh the mview. This works in something like 10-15 seconds for 60.000 rows in our environment.

Comment: Which process takes a minute? Step 1? Step 2? Or Step 3? Or all together it takes a minute? If all together, do you have a breakdown of the time for each step? And what is the problem if your computer is busy for 4 minutes per day?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the entire process takes 1 minute. I know this is nothing if you work 8 hours a day but I'd like to make the application as efficient as possible. Step 1 takes about 10 seconds, 2 takes 5 and it's C# that takes up the rest because it has to loop trough it a lot.

Comment: @KimBergHansen, I gonna have a look at your suggestion.

Comment: C# and not SQL*Loader for step 3? I would definitely benchmark SQL*Loader before writing too much C#...

Comment: If you are looping through the CSV file in C# in order to insert the data one row at a time, then definitely an external table can help you speed up the process. Once you have the external table, you can refresh the Oracle data either completely by materialized view (simple) or just changes by a MERGE statement. Only thing that might  possibly be an issue for you is, that the CSV file has to be created either on the database server or at the least a share that the database server has access to.

Comment: Do you even need a CSV file?  Can you create a database link between Oracle and SAP and directly pull the data into Oracle with a single SQL statement?

Comment: I have asked the people that work with SAP that it is not possible. So I first have to export to csv and then into Oracle. No big deal since I reduced the time significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the comments helped me reduce the time. First Truncate, then insert all rows with the Oracle DataAccess library instead of OleDb.

Comment: If you need to delete all the rows from a table, you can just TRUNCATE it.

Comment: @alikox, thanks for the tip to use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE. Much faster!